# XDocument.Descendants() is empty even though there is content in the XDocument

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, kml

I am loading this KML: http://www.mcallen.net/Files/docs/traffic/bike/kml/McBikeRoutes.kml

into an XDocument, and if I look at the XDocument in the debugger, it appears to be correctly populated with the contents of the file.

However, when I try to access any descendants, no matter what I do it comes up empty.

```
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Assets/McBikeRoutes.kml");
    var d = xDoc.Descendants(); // <-- Empty result
```

In the code above, the McBikeRoutes.kml is an exact copy of the file linked above, I just added it to my project manually so it's getting it internally instead of online.

Also, I can verify that the xDoc DOES load the file, as if I observe it in the debugger, I can see it contains the complete KML document contents.

However, no mater how I try to access the descendants, the result is always empty.

I tried including the default namespace and all other namespaces in the document but no matter what I do there are no results.

I finally just tried xDoc.Descendants() to get everything and THIS ALSO resulted empty!

I tried xDoc.Root.Descendants() and xDoc.Document.Descendants(), as well as xDoc.Elements(), xDoc.Root.Elements() and xDoc.Document.Elements() and EVERTHING returns an empty result, even though there clearly is info in the XDocument.

Strangely enough, if I do:

```
((XElement)xDoc.FirstNode)
```

I do get the first descendant XElement! but if I do this:

```
((XElement)xDoc.FirstNode).Descendants()
```

I STILL get no results (same thing when I tried Elements())!

anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? is it because the document is a KML?

Comment: not sure if it matters but the DocumentType is null for the XDocument as well.

Comment: it turns out xDoc.Nodes() is also empty, even though xDoc.FirstNode returns XNode of the first node in the doc... gah wtf!

Comment: `((XElement)xDoc.FirstNode` does not have balanced brackets. It may be useful to post your code for a minimal failing example and indicate values (e.g. through print). It may be that you are casting elements incorrectly

Comment: sorry that was just a typo in my post, not the original code, fixed it above. there's not really much code to post, I literally did XDocument.Load and then xDoc.Descendants() which is empty

Comment: what does ((XElement)xDoc.FirstNode) return? I would expect the "kml" element but it's some time since I did LINQ.

Comment: it does indeed return the "kml" element, and it shows the name and namespace which matches the one I'm using, but when I use it in the Descendants(kml + "kml") or Descendants (kml + "Document") (where kml is the default namespace) it always comes up empty. Why would it give me a result using FirstNode, but not with Descendants (or Nodes() for that matter!)

Comment: You posted `Descendants()` but it seems like you are actually calling it with arguments. You MUST post the exact code. I now guess it is your arguments that are the problem. It's not reasonable to expect us to guess what your code is.

Comment: You have posted one document http://www.mcallen.net/Files/docs/traffic/bike/kml/McBikeRoutes.kml for us to look at and another document "Assets/McBikeRoutes.kml" that you are using. I don't know what is in the latter one or even if it exists. I suggest you write a simple program that prints in sequence: (a) the contents of the file (b) xDoc (c) xDoc.FirstNode (d)  xDoc.firstNode.Descendants(). Do this on a short file.

Comment: sorry I should have clarified. The local document Assets/McBikeroutes.kml is the exact same file as the one linked. I simply downloaded it and placed it in my project so I don't actually have to access it online. missing file or something similar couldn't be the issue, because the XDocument is loaded and when I observe it I can see the full document from the KML file...

Comment: How are you determining that Documents() is empty. The contract is "An IEnumerable<T> of XElement containing the descendant elements of the XContainer." Have you iterated over the Descendants? show the code

Comment: I am now confident I know what the answer is but until you actually post CODE showing that Descendants() is "empty" (your words, but not a technical term) I can't do more

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by code, but here is a screencap of the code above, with the result in the debugger showing that there are no items in the Descendants property. If i'm misreading this result, I apologize for being confusing, but as far as I can tell the result is empty. http://sdrv.ms/11xzFHO

Comment: I tried to parse the provided file. At first it seems empty, but in fact it's not. Just expand the result or do a foreach loop!

Answer (score 0):

I am now transferring this to an answer.

There are two methods for Descendants() 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants.aspx

```
Public method   Descendants()   
   Returns a collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, 
   in document order. (Inherited from XContainer.)
Public method   Descendants(XName)  
   Returns a filtered collection of the descendant elements for this 
   document or element, in document order. Only elements that have a 
   matching XName are included in the collection. (Inherited from XContainer.)
```

If you call `Descendants(XName)` with the wrong arguments it is highly likely you will get no descendants. If you use `Descendants()` [sic] I would expect to get all descendants.

The reason `FirstNode` gives a non-empty answer is that you cannot alter its behaviour with arguments and so you **cannot** avoid calling it correctly.

Please **post your actual code**

UPDATE. This discussion is not the most effective way of solving your problem. You should construct an SSCCE (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions ) " Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example."

What you should do is create a SMALL example. I would take your KML file and create the minimal valid subset that can be read in and where you can EXPLICITLY show the methods that you think are failing. (BTW I think it extremely unlikely that the problem is KML- I think it is how you are calling the methods and or what you are expecting). I would try to read the XML string so it can be posted on SO and give the complete code that you are using and what you actually get. Words such as "empty" are not precise enough - does it mean that the IEnumeration has zero elements as reported by some function? (My knowledge of XDocument is a few years old).

If you create an SSCCE I might be able to help you. (I don't know). But at least we can express your problem in precise terms.

UPDATE:
Since you have not posted any code I shall make guess as to what is wrong:
Your Descendants() and Elements() do actually contain Nodes but that you are not interrogating them properly. 
If you had posted code you I would have spent much less time and given you an answer.

UPDATE
Thanks for the debugger snapshot. I had guessed that this was where the problem initially manifests itself. Firstly, you must use precise terminology - you wrote "empty" but the debugger labels this as "null". They are completely different and use of one for the other will mislead.

My suspicion was and is that you were unable to use your debugger to reveal the descendant elements. I think you and your debugger don't understand each other. This is impossible to debug over the net.

Descendants() is an IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> Descendants()
```

My C# /Linq is rusty and I do not have a working system but in general terms this means that it provides methods to get the elements, in order. Its only method is:

GetEnumerator() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx)

You are going to have to work out how to get the descendants in CODE (not the debugger) so you need to learn how to iterate through an IEnumerable. From memory this would be something like:

```
foreach (XElement descendant : getDescendants()) {
    printSomehowOrDoSomething(descendant);
}
```

If you write the actual code you want to use and run it, then either it will do what you want or you will have a much clearer idea of your problem that you can communicate. (I don't know why your debugger says "null" - it may be technically correct but misleading. Also your screencap (+ button) suggests that the enumeration has children.

Simply: Forget the debugger (it's not code) and **write the code you want to execute**, as simply as possibly in the first instance (no more than 10 lines). The value of a small snippet (SSCCE) is that it is reproducible immediately by others - they can cut and paste and run in their own systems. Code, and its errors, is far more precise than debuggers. BTW I hope you are using Unit Testing and Test-driven development - if you had created a failing test then it would be clear where the problem was.

Comment: you say "If you use Descendants() I would expect to get all descendants" and that's what I would expect as well. I posted the code as you requested, but like I said, I'm literally just loading the document and checking the descendants of the XDocument. If I look at the contents of the XDocument indeed all the xml content is there, but no matter what I try I cannot get anything from Descendants.